# How to request permissions for location sub-page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I'm working on a project that imports ratings and recommendations for Facebook pages. To do that according to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing/#reviews) you need the `manage_pages` permission.

I'm able to request this permission for regular Facebook pages and then pull the ratings for those pages. However, when it comes to locations that are 'child' pages of a regular page, I can't pull the ratings and can see no way to request the permissions for them.

Attempting to access the ratings of a location with the parent page access token when I have the manage_pages permission for the parent page returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#283) Requires manage_pages permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 283,
    "fbtrace_id": "GEXG+g4MOSb"
  }
}
```

Accessing the ratings on the parent page works fine.

Trying to call `FB.login` on the web SDK with `profile_selector_ids` set to a list of child pages doesn't respect the value and will put the entire list of pages that the user manages irrespective of the value of `enable_profile_selector`.

Comment: Does your user have admin rights on the child page as well?

Comment: Yes, they have the admin role on all pages involved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been because of a bug on Facebook's side. There was a [support thread](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/555090991660706/) on Facebook Developers where the author couldn't access the ratings endpoint for locations.

> When hitting the GET /page_id/ratings endpoint (using the page access_token from GET /locations) we receive a missing manage_page permission error

That thread was closed as of today (2019-06-17) and I am again able to access ratings for locations using the master page's access token.